Client complained to me about a colleague. Temporary pm is handling it. Should I bring it up with management?
I am on two teams simultaneously. On one team I have a colleague, "Bob" who is on the same level as I. Bob and I are in support roles for other teams in the organization and generally don't work together much. However due to a quirk with a project, I was pulled into the second team temporarily which is one of the teams that Bob supports. This is already an awkward situation, where I am simultaneously Bob's same-level colleague and also someone Bob is directly supporting. It is important to note that although Bob is supporting this second team no one on that team has any supervisory status over Bob. It's more of a set up where Bob has been delegated a set of tasks that must be completed, and this delegation ultimately came from mine and Bob's manager. It's sort of like the team's project manager sent a list of tasks to our manager and our manager got Bob to do them. This is how all of this works for every such team, and the PM's are not considered managers of our team members.
When I started on the second team I spoke to its project manager and we agreed that any stuff that Bob had to help with would go through the pm and not me. Bob and I also agreed to this. Up until yesterday Bob and I had a good professional relationship and I had no reason to suspect anything was amiss. We all did the best we could with an awkward situation.
Yesterday however the pm and I received a phone call from a client who was very dissatisfied with something Bob did. The pm has agreed to handle it, but I'm fairly certain that mine and Bob's manager on our original team is going to get involved, which will bring me in to this anyway. Therefore I feel that I should also bring this up with our manager as a heads up so it doesn't look like I'm trying to hide anything.
Should I bring this up with management, and if so, how?

Why is this your problem?

Why is this an awkward situation? What exactly is your beef here? Why don't you just focus on your job and let Bob do his (and let him deal with the fallout if he screws up)?

If your manager gets involved as Bobs manager, then they do. I don't see how you get involved though. You did not witness the alleged dissatisfactory actions of Bob. All you could do is confirm that the client said what they said. I don't see any role for you in this.
As long as it is a business problem that poses no real danger, the PM said they will handle it. It is literally their job to handle it. So let them handle it.


Yesterday however the pm and I received a phone call from a client who
was very dissatisfied with something Bob did. The pm has agreed to
handle it, but I'm fairly certain that mine and Bob's manager on our
original team is going to get involved, which will bring me in to this
anyway. Therefore I feel that I should also bring this up with our
manager as a heads up so it doesn't look like I'm trying to hide
anything.

When something like this happens, you have an obligation to your employer to let management know. That has already happened.
If this is a major issue that could result in the company getting sued or facing criminal charges, then you could also alert your manager. That way you are on the record as having reported it.
If it is a minor issue, I would not feel obligated to tell Bob's manager. You might not know the whole history of the client, and the 2nd team. The PM of the 2nd team knows the whole picture.
